# Повторяющиеся значений в MySQL

Tags: mysql, запрос, mysql-workbench

Есть таблица данных содержащая названия производителей мониторов(manufacturer) и их тип(monitor_type). Необходимо вывести название производителей у которых есть несколько типов мониторов.Помогите, пожалуйста составить, запрос.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте запрос

```
SELECT manufacturer, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM 'table_name' GROUP BY manufacturer HAVING cnt > 1
```

https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/4.6.php [1]

Comment: В общем случае запрос неверный.